# Binding request to a form does not work for collection type

Tags: forms, symfony, symfony-2.0

I don't use any ORM for entities. This form is built for sending email only.

In my Controller I have this:

```
    $builder = $this->myHelper
        ->createBuilder('form', null)

        ->add('my_group', 'collection', array(
        'type' => 'text',
        'label' => 'mylabel'
    ));

    $builder->get('my_group')->add('first_node', 'text');
    $builder->get('my_group')->add('second_node', 'text');

    return $builder->getForm();
```

The form is rendered OK - with additional input fields as expected. But when it comes to binding request to form in my post-data handling action - `my_group` field comes empty (even due to fact that this field is posted in `'form'` array):

```
// var_dump($request->get('form'));die;
array
 'my_group' => 
   array
     'first_node' => string 'asdasd' (length=3)
     'second_node' => string 'asdasda' (length=3)
```

When I bind request to form, I have null in `my_group` collection field (all other inputs are OK).

```
$form->bindRequest($request);
$formData = $form->getData();
var_dump($formData);die; // Outputs my_group => null
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

**UPDATE 1**

Part of Twig template (requested by [Max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1073535/max-malecki)):

```
{% for field in form.children if 'hidden' not in field.vars.types %}
    ...
    {% elseif 'collection' in field.vars.types %}
        <th>{{ form_label(field) }}</th>
        <td>
            {% for collection_field in field %}
                {{ form_widget(collection_field) }}
            {% endfor %}
        </td>
    {% else %}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: can you show me your form twig?

Comment: @MaxMałecki It would be hard, because real code is much complicated and I'd have to extract pieces from there and change variable names. How twig can affect form submission? Even if this data comes in request under the `form` array - doesn't it mean that form is submitted correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved, when I defined `FormType` for needed collection:

```
class MyType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('first_node', 'text');
        $builder->add('second_node', 'text');
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array();
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'mytype';
    }
}
```

Then I used it in builder:

```
$builder = $this->myHelper
    ->createBuilder('form', null)

    ->add('my_group', new MyType(), array(
    'label' => 'mylabel'
));


return $builder->getForm();
```

After this data was bound to form correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create:

1. form class
2. template of a form (with macro)
3. jQuery script to manipulate the data in the form

Check this tutorial :)

http://toni.uebernickel.info/2012/03/15/an-example-of-symfony2-collectiontype-form-field-prototype.html

Comment: What for do I need jQuery? I don't want to dynamically add inputs :) I just want to have composite fields, which consists of two inputs.